# xPages - set javascript variable by reading JSON from URL

Tags: javascript, json, rest, xpages

I have an xAgent (based on JSONandRest example in openntf by Nikolas Heildoff) which returns me a json. this xpage is nothing by there is a call to java method which returns JSON.
My problem is to have this JSON read into a JS variable so I am able to play with it.

I would like to do something like:

```
var myJson = getJson("Json.xsp")
```

Thanks in advance
Arun

Answer (score 2):

You can use the *fromJson* method:

```
var json = "{a:'123', b: 'abc'}";
var obj = fromJson( json );
println( obj.a );
```

This sends *123* to the console.